# Is it possible to insert debugger statements in React application remotely?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, remote-debugging

I'd like to remotely activate debugging in my website. For example, I would deploy my website to staging (not production but not local either). I would like to be able to insert `debugger` statements if necessary in the deployed website after deployment, dynamically. Is it possible?

I was searching for remotely debugging javascript applications and was surprised to not find anything like I'm looking for. I found a few services like [remote.js](https://remotejs.com) or [vorlon.js](http://www.vorlonjs.io/#getting-started) but they just let you inspect the HTML/CSS and maybe perform some actions on plain javascript (by selecting some DOM nodes).

I guess I'm looking for something like `node --inspect` but for javascript.

Comment: Use the browser developer tools to add breakpoints

Comment: @azium you mean when debugging locally?

Comment: No I mean anywhere.. it doesn't matter if it's production or not. Are you using source maps?

Comment: Technically everything in the browser is "local"

Comment: @azium I use source maps when not in production. I don't understand how I can add debugger statements on a website which doesn't run on localhost? If I refresh the statement is lost. And I'm not sure how I can use sourcemaps when deploying to understand where to place the debugger statement.